# Get element out of parsed JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, json

I can't seem to pull out elements of parsed JSON object.

```
var thisObj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
   console.log(JSON.parse(req.responseText));
```

Here is what is logged:

```
Object
data: "{"sVar":"sdf","nVar":"","dVar":"","cVar":"#000000"}"
```

I have tried the following methods

`thisObj.data[sVar]`

`thisObj.data.sVar`

They all produced `undefined`.

It doesn't seem to be in an array.
Any ideas?

Console.log(req.responseText)...

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"sVar\":\"asdf\",\"nVar\":\"\",\"dVar\":\"\",\"cVar\":\"#000000\"}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
    "Content-Length": "52", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Origin": "http://localhost:63342", 
    "Referer": "http://localhost:63342/AssignmentAJAX/weather.html", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "cVar": "#000000", 
    "dVar": "", 
    "nVar": "", 
    "sVar": "asdf"
  }, 
  "origin": "65.128.122.251", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the plain response, please? It almost looks like `.data` was a string

Comment: Yep. Console log req and req.responseText and post them please.

Comment: `data` is clearly a string. You need to parse it first. Better yet: Fix your server side code to node double encode your data.

Answer (score 1):

The `data` property of `thisObj` is a string representing data object. You should parse it too. For example:

```
var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
var data = JSON.parse(response.data);
console.log(data.sVar);
```

Comment: Yes somehow when I did this is got double parsed, as Felix Kling mentioned; however, this method of parsing it twice worked.  I later went back and fixed the root issue of my request to the server.  Thanks!